# BackHandler in react native not working properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, handler, back, stack-navigator

I Am trying To implement Back Handler in react native Stack Navigation.
I have
splashScreen, Home, Demo

in Home Screen I have exit app function on back press. when I press back button from Home Screen then this function is calling.

but when I press Back button from Demo Screen then also this exit function calling. please help me what is wrong with my code..

here is my App.js

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="splashScreen"
          component={splashScreen}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={Home}
          options={{headerShown: true}}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Demo"
          component={Demo}
          options={{headerShown: true}}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
```

here is my Home.js

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  handleBackButton = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Exit App',
      'Exiting the application?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp(),
        },
      ],
      {
        cancelable: false,
      },
    );
    return true;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

render(){
return()
}
```

here is Demo.js

```
handleBackButton = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }
render(){
return()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be

```
handleBackButton = () => {
  if(!this.props.navigation.isFocused()){
    return false
  }
  //rest of your codes
}
```